# how to extract some data from cells?

Tags: r, extract

I would like to extract number information in cells. My data looks like this.

```
      item       stock
PRE 24DX4SX15G    200      
PLS 12RX10SX15G   200
ADU 24PX200ML     200
NIS 18PX40SX11G   200
REF 500GX12D      200
```

i want to extract the numbers which located besides alphabet D,R and P. I want to use this number to do multiplication with the stock. For example like this.

```
          item       stock    pcs    total
    PRE 24DX4SX15G    200      24    4800
    PLS 12RX10SX15G   200      12    2400 
    ADU 24PX200ML     200      24    4800
    NIS 18PX40SX11G   200      18    3600
    REF 500GX12D      200      12    2400
```

anyone know how to extract the numbers? thanks very much in advance

Comment: how to do that seperate? because the number position is not always located after the "space"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a suitable regular expression:

```
df$pcs <- gsub("^(.*[^0-9]|)([0-9]+)[DPR].*", "\\2", df$item)
df$pcs <- as.numeric(df$pcs)
```

Explanation:

- `[DPR]` means we are matching one character which is either D, P or R
- `[^0-9]` means we are matching anything *but* one of the digits 0-9
- The parentheses create two regular expression groups, first being a prefix and the second being the actual number we want to match.
- we can use the second group in substitute by preceding 2 with a backslash; only to get a backslash in R, we need to enter two backslashes: `\\2`
- The number of interest (preceding a D, P or R) can be found at different locations. Either it is at the beginning, in which case we should match `^([0-9]+)[DPR]`, or it is somewhere inside the text. Therefore we have to first match the beginning of string (`^`) and then alternatively match either nothing or anything that does not end in a number (`.*[^0-9]`).

**EDIT**: with the stringr library (as @yamabrina showed in the other answer) the regular expression is much simpler:

```
library(stringr)
df$pcs <- as.numeric(str_sub(str_extract(df$item, "[0-9]+[DPR]"), 1, -2))
```

Comment: how about if I want to extract number which were preceded by character "SB" and "KLR"? how do I add this?

Comment: I don't understand. "SB" is not a character but a string. Please be more specific. Do you mean to say "first S or B, then K, L or R", or "first `SB`, then `KLR`"?

Comment: i mean string. im sorry

Comment: To extract a numer which is preceded by either "SB" or "KLR" you just use `(SB|KLR)([0-9]+)`. The `(x|y)` construct means "either pattern x or pattern y" (you can add more patterns, like `(x|y|z)`.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(stringr)

dataset <- read.table(text = '      item       stock
PRE 24DX4SX15G    200      
PLS 12RX10SX15G   200
ADU 24PX200ML     200
NIS 18PX40SX11G   200
REF 500GX12D      200',
                      header = TRUE)

dataset %>%
  mutate(pcs = as.numeric(x = str_sub(string = str_extract(string = item,
                                                           pattern = "\\d+[DRP]"),
                                      start = 1,
                                      end = -2)),
         total = (stock * pcs))
#>          item stock pcs total
#> 1  24DX4SX15G   200  24  4800
#> 2 12RX10SX15G   200  12  2400
#> 3   24PX200ML   200  24  4800
#> 4 18PX40SX11G   200  18  3600
#> 5    500GX12D   200  12  2400
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Hope this helps.

Comment: i want to ask. what does the number means in start and end? I mean the "start=1" and "end=-2")

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto `str_sub` selects a substring from the supplied string. We need to specify the beginning and end of such a substring. `start` indicates the position of the first character that will be in the selected substring, and `end` means that of the last character. Here, `1` means starting from the very beginning of the supplied string, and `-2` means the second last character.